# How to use the input stream timestamp, as the output stream timestamp?

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

I use this command to convert:

```
ffmpeg -copyts -i test.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -f flv test-out.flv
```

but the timestamp in the output file is different from original file.

the starting timestamp of the test.flv is not 0 and There are I、B、P-frames

How to use the input stream timestamp, as the output stream timestamp ?

Your help will be much appreciated.

FFmpeg's output:

```
ffmpeg -copyts -i test.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -f flv test-out.flv
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on May  3 2013 10:11:18 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-swscale --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-filter=movie --enable-frei0r --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --extra-ldflags=-ldl --enable-shared --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-encoder=png --enable-encoder=bmp --enable-encoder=wmv1 --enable-encoder=wmv2
libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, flv, from 'test.flv':
Metadata:
audiochannels   : 1
audiodevice     : ?(Realtek High Definition Au
audioinputvolume: 75
author          : 
copyright       : 
creationdate    : Tue Apr 15 17:08:22 2014
                : 
description     : 
fmleversion     : 3.2.0.9932
keywords        : 
lastkeyframetimestamp: 83030
lasttimestamp   : 83079
presetname      : Medium Bandwidth (300 Kbps) - VP6
rating          : 
title           : 
videodevice     : HD WebCam
videokeyframe_frequency: 5
Duration: 00:01:23.08, start: 10.000000, bitrate: 257 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: vp6f, yuv420p, 320x240, 204 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 49 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast FastShuffle SSEMisalign LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] 264 - core 118 r0+7M 0176d43 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'test-out.flv':
Metadata:
audiochannels   : 1
audiodevice     : ?(Realtek High Definition Au
audioinputvolume: 75
author          : 
copyright       : 
creationdate    : Tue Apr 15 17:08:22 2014
                : 
description     : 
fmleversion     : 3.2.0.9932
keywords        : 
lastkeyframetimestamp: 83030
lasttimestamp   : 83079
presetname      : Medium Bandwidth (300 Kbps) - VP6
rating          : 
title           : 
videodevice     : HD WebCam
videokeyframe_frequency: 5
encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp6f -> libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 2476 fps=119 q=29.0 Lsize=    2476kB time=00:01:33.13 bitrate= 217.8kbits/s  
video:2013kB audio:385kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.288641%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] frame I:10    Avg QP:17.28  size: 12163
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] frame P:2050  Avg QP:21.13  size:   899
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] frame B:416   Avg QP:27.54  size:   230
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] consecutive B-frames: 77.4%  0.2%  0.8% 21.5%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] mb I  I16..4:  6.5% 81.8% 11.7%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  1.4%  0.0%  P16..4: 30.2%  5.1%  7.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:55.8%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 22.5%  1.6%  0.5%  direct: 0.8%  skip:74.0%  L0:49.2% L1:43.8% BI: 7.0%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] 8x8 transform intra:77.4% inter:83.6%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 60.3% 61.2% 18.2% inter: 14.7% 15.7% 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 45% 36%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 28% 48%  2%  1%  2%  3%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 25% 14%  5%  6%  7%  7%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 21% 27%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] ref P L0: 74.2%  8.4% 11.4%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] ref B L0: 86.9%  9.4%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] ref B L1: 94.8%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 0x135366c0] kb/s:198.42
```

The reason is or not that I have only changed the bit rate, but did not change the frame rate or resolution,
I don't know the The relationship between the three.

[image: the Timestamp comparison of input and output files]